# ¿Cómo obtener todos los valores de un td especificado con un id con jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

Estoy imprimiendo en el html un información que viene de php con multiples registros, usando un foreach; pero quisiera obtener de todos los registros "valores" que vienen en el campo td con el id="FechaRegistro" usando jquery, pero no tengo la más mínima idea de como se puede realizar, ¿Cómo se podría realizar?.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    <tr>
         <td>#<?php echo $datax->Codigo; ?></td>
         <td><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <?php echo $datax->PrimerNombre." ".$datax->PrimerApellido." [ ".$datax->NombreCompleto." ]"; ?></td>
         <td id="FechaRegistro"> <?php echo $datax->FechaSolicitud; ?></td>
   </tr>
```

Intente realizarlo de la siguiente forma pero solo me tomo el ultimo registro:

```
$('#FechaRegistro').each(function(index){
    console.log(index + " : " + $(this).text());
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes usar el mismo `id` para diferentes elementos.  Necesitas usar una clase asi:

```js
$('.FechaRegistro').each(function(index){
    console.log(index + " : " + $(this).text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
         <td>Codigo</td>
         <td><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Nombre</td>
         <td class="FechaRegistro"> 2019-09-17</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
         <td>Codigo</td>
         <td><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Nombre</td>
         <td class="FechaRegistro"> 2019-09-18</td>
   </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo me funciono, tengo una pregunta si quisiera cambiar el valor de la fecha como lo podría hacer con jquery, ósea al mismo tiempo que lo recorro cambio el valor por otro (digamos que otra fecha distinta)

Comment: De nada.  Puedes usar `$(this).text()`

Answer (score 1):

Los IDs se sobrescriben y solo queda uno (la idea es que sean únicos), entonces en vez de usar IDs, usa clases.

```
    <tr>
       <td>#<?php echo $datax->Codigo; ?></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <?php echo $datax->PrimerNombre." ".$datax->PrimerApellido." [ ".$datax->NombreCompleto." ]"; ?></td>
       <td class="FechaRegistro"> <?php echo $datax->FechaSolicitud; ?></td>
    </tr>
```

y para recorrerlo usa

```
$('.FechaRegistro').each(function(index){
    console.log(index + " : " + $(this).text());
})
```