# Recuperar valor de un select y mostrar el mismo valor en un input que se encuentra dentro de una estructura repetitiva

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery

Buen día , soy principiante en programacion, tengo un registro de notas que listo en una tabla dentro de una estructura Foreach pero mi problema es cuando trato de seleccionar un option del select que solo me devuelve el valor el el primer input y no en toda la estructura repetitiva desde ya gracias por la ayuda adjunto una foto[image: En el select tengo 3 trimestres por cada trimestre en el value me muestra un numero distinto 1- trimestre = 1, 2-trimestre = 2 y 3_ trimestre = 3]

```
            <label for="">CLICK PARA CARGAR LOS CRITERIOS A SER EVALUADOS</label>
            <input type="button" value="CARGAR CRITERIOS" onclick="location.reload()" />
          
          
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Elija el trimestre a evaluar:</label>
              <select style="width: 100%;" name="trimes"  onchange="mostrarResultado(this.value)" id="trimes" class="form-control trimestre" required>
                <option value="">Seleccione</option>
                <?php echo mostrartrimestres($obj); ?>
              </select>
            </div>
          

            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="tabla_nueva">
              
              <form action="guardar_notas.php" method="post" id="formGuardar_notas" >
              <?php foreach ((array)$result as $row) { ?>
               
                <tbody>
                  <tr id="fila_repetir" class="fila-fija">
                    <td class="tamaño"><?php echo $row['datos_alumno']; ?>
                    <input class="llenar" type="text" name="idtri[]" id="idtri" value="">
                     
                    <td id="criterios" class="cri1">
                      <input class="celda1" type="text" name="nota1[]" id="nota1" value="0" oninput="securePhoneNumber(this)" required>
                    </td>
                    <td id="criterios" class="cri2">
                      <input class="celda2" type="text" name="nota2[]" id="nota2" value="0" oninput="securePhoneNumber(this)" required>
                    </td>

                    <?php if ($criterio3 == NULL) {
                    } else { ?>

                      <td id="criterios" class="cri3">
                        <input class="celda3" type="text" name="nota3[]" id="nota3" value="0" oninput="securePhoneNumber(this)" required>
                      </td>
                    <?php } ?>


                    <?php if ($criterio4 == NULL) {
                    } else { ?>

                      <td id="criterios" class="cri4">
                        <input class="celda4" type="text" name="nota4[]" id="nota4" value="0" oninput="securePhoneNumber(this)" required>
                      </td>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php if ($criterio5 == NULL) {
                    } else { ?>

                      <td id="criterios" class="cri5">
                        <input class="celda5" type="text" name="nota5[]" id="nota5" value="0" oninput="securePhoneNumber(this)" required>
                      </td>
                    <?php } ?>


                    <td> <input class="promedio" type="hidden" id="filas" placeholder="" readonly required> </td>

                    <td> <input class="promedio" type="text" name="promedio[]" id="promedio" placeholder="" readonly required> </td>

                  </tr>

                <?php
              };
                ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>


            <div class="box-footer">
              <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="btnGuardar"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Guardar </button>
              
              </center>
            </div>
            </form>

          </div>
```

---

```
<script> function mostrarResultado(value){ if(value !==
"Seleccione")   document.getElementById("idtri").value= value; else 
document.getElementById("idtri").value= ''; } </script>
```

Comment: Tu problema es que estas usando el mismo `id` para todas las filas.  Los `id` deben de ser unicos.  Utiliza clases en lugar de `id`.

Comment: tendras algun ejemplo amigo ya lo intente de todas formas y no logro mostrar el valor

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/448533/c%c3%b3mo-obtener-todos-los-valores-de-un-td-especificado-con-un-id-con-jquery/448536#448536

Comment: muchas gracias amigo logre solucionar mi problema